# HTML, CSS problems: can't understand why page is not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive

Well guys, I have this code written from a "collegue", who forgot to make the site responsive (no scroll bar and no overflow: hidden).

Now, i'm not able to understand what's wrong, I've tried to set body size to 100% (height and width) and to remove all px's size, but still nothing changed. Can you give me some help please?
The code above is the original one, without my edit.

```css
html, .container{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
    background-image: url('../img/sfondo_blocchi.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

div#box1{
    width: 90%;
    margin-top:8%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 425px;
}


/* Slideshow Manual */

.hidden1 {
  display: none;
}

#slideshow {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transition: all 0.15s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s;
  transition: all 0.15s;
}

.hover_img:hover {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.09);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.09);
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.textmenu{
  color:snow;
}

/* Popup container - can be anything you want */

.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


/* The actual popup */

.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}


/* Popup arrow */

.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}


/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */

.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}


/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>RezzaCapaMundi</title><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="CustomCss/styleBio.css">
     <script src="js/audio.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark">
       <a class="navbar-brand" id="id5" href="Intro.html"><span class="textmenu">Pagina iniziale</span></a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
         <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link custom" href="Home.html"><span class="textmenu">Home</span><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link custom" href="#"><span class="textmenu">Biglietti</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link custom" href="#"><span class="textmenu">Mappa</span></a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link custom" href="#"><span class="textmenu">Quiz</span></a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </nav>
     </header>
    
     <div class="container" id="box1">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col text-center">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 4%;" >
             <img src="img/biografia/foto1.jpeg" style="width:89%; border-radius:5px; margin-top:6%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" style="font-size:18px; margin-top: 4%; text-align:justify">
             <b style="text-align: left"><strong>INCIPIT</strong></b>
             <br>
             <b>Mi chiamo Michele Salvemini, sono figlio di un operaio e di una maestra.
              Il mio nonno paterno era falegname, quello materno era contadino.
              Io sono diventato cantante, non me ne vogliano.
              Sono nato a Molfetta nel 1973, precisamente il 9 Ottobre, come John Lennon con il quale ho in comune solo questa data e.. chissà.. forse lo stesso epilogo.
              Da piccolino mi iscrissi ad una scuola di musica per imparare a suonare il pianoforte.
              Dopo 3 mesi lasciai la scuola di musica col desiderio di abitare in una baita riscaldata da un camino alimentato dalla carcassa di un Bosendorfer gran coda.
              Decisi che la musica non faceva per me. Il giorno dopo iniziai a comporre i miei primi pezzi.</b>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom: 4%; margin-top: 6%; text-align:justify" >
             <b style="text-align: left"><strong>ESORDI</strong></b>
             <br>
             <b>Dopo aver sfornato decine di demo che torneranno utili con la mia dipartita,
             magari arricchiti dagli interventi di questo o quell’altro rapper che presteranno la voce ai cd postumi,
             arrivò il momento della prima pubblicazione.
             <br>
             Era il 1996, mi facevo chiamare Mikimix e pubblicavo dischi della stessa qualità degli ultimi dischi pubblicati dai cantanti di qualità.
             A quel tempo ero troppo ingenuo per sospettare che mi avrebbero infastidito un’intera vita con questa storia di Mikimix perciò decisi di continuare…
             E scusate se sputo nel piatto in cui non ho mangiato.</b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center" style="margin-top: 5%;" >
             <img src="img/biografia/foto2.jpg" style="width:89%; border-radius:5px; margin-top:6%;">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 text-center" style="margin-top: 5%;" >
             <img src="img/biografia/foto3.jpg" style="width:89%; border-radius:5px; margin-top:6%;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:4%; margin-top:6%; text-align:justify">
             <b style="text-align: left"><strong>POST-MIKIMIX</strong></b>
             <br>
             <b>Dopo una serie di riflessioni emo, di momenti depressivi e di fallimenti amorosi, capìi che era arrivato il momento di seguire la strada dei miei avi: andare a lavorare.
             Era chiaro che la musica proprio non faceva per me.
             Il giorno dopo iniziai a comporre nuovi pezzi.
             Mi crebbero i capelli, il pizzetto e altro..
             Ero pronto a rivelare cazzutamente il mio pensiero sulle cose, senza compromessi.
             Nel 1998 inizia il mio percorso come Caparezza col demo “Ricomincio da Capa”.
             La musica è cambiata e inizio la trafila delle jam e dei
              <div class="popup" onclick="FunctionTour()"><u>concerti</u>
               <span class="popuptext" id="tour"><a style="color:white" href="Tour.html">Vai a scoprire il tour 2018.</a></span>
              </div>
              in pizzeria col vicinato che chiede di abbassare il volume durante l’esibizione (e non lo fa con garbo).</b>
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
    
          <div class="carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5" style="font-size:20px; margin-bottom:4%;margin-top:3%; text-align:justify">
             <b style="text-align: left"><strong>PRESENTE</strong></b>
             <br>
             <b>
             Siamo nel 2018 e viene pubblicato il mio settimo
             <div class="popup" onclick="FunctionAlbum()"><u>album</u>
              <span class="popuptext" id="album"><a style="color:white;font-size:15px;" href="Album.html">Vai a vedere tutti i suoi album e demo.</a></span>
             </div>
             in studio (“Prisoner 709”), ho all’attivo centinaia di concerti e mi sono comprato un pianoforte..(l’inverno è stato particolarmente duro).
             Che dire.. Per me la vita di un’artista è meno interessante della sua opera ma in un'altra sezione vi lascio comunque delle
    
              <div class="popup" onclick="FunctionApprofondimenti()"><u>informazioni</u>
               <span class="popuptext" id="approfondimenti"><a style="color:white; font-size:15px;" href="Approfondimenti.html">Scopri chicche ed altro.</a></span>
              </div>.
              utili perché la sostanza va, la forma resta..
             </b>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7" style="margin-top:5%;">
             <img src="img/biografia/foto4.jpg" style="width:89%; height: 80%; border-radius:5px; margin-top:1%;">
            </div>
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <div class="container" id="box2">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2" style="right:30%;">
        <img onclick="clicksound.playclip()" src="img/pulsanti/info.png"  id="myBtn" class="hover_img" width="40%" alt=""/>
       </div>
    
       <div class="col-lg-8" align="center">
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
         <a onclick="clicksound.playclip()" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"> <img src="img/pulsanti/slide-prev.png" width="12%" class="hover_img" alt=""/></a>
        </a>
        &nbsp &nbsp
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
         <a onclick="clicksound.playclip()" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" ><img src="img/pulsanti/slide-suc.png" width="12%" class="hover_img" alt=""/></a>
        </a>
       </div>
    
       <div class="col-lg-2" style="left:20%;">
        <audio controls id="player">
         <source src="audio/prisoner1.flac" type="audio/mpeg">
         Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
        </audio>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    
     <script>
        function FunctionAlbum() {
            clicksound.playclip();
            var popup = document.getElementById("album");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }

        function FunctionTour() {
            clicksound.playclip();
            var popup = document.getElementById("tour");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }

        function FunctionApprofondimenti() {
            clicksound.playclip();
            var popup = document.getElementById("approfondimenti");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/audio.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: In what way do you expect it to respond?

Comment: I need no overflow, no scroll bar, just a page that will resize itself on the various display' size

Comment: Maybe your defenition of responsive is off. Responsive means it can scale to no matter the screen size. "no scroll bar and no overflow: hidden" just depends on the content of the page.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, as I said I think the problems is in some content's size setted in px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `left 20%` or adding `width: auto` from/ to the audio container div solved the horizontal scrollbar

```
<div class="col-lg-2" style="left:20%; width:auto">
    <audio controls id="player">
        <source src="audio/prisoner1.flac" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 audio.
    </audio>
</div>
```

This is because the div is set to `width: 100%` in the grid-framework.scss by the `col-lg-2` class. Together with the `left 20%` it pushes the div outside and past the other content hense the horizontal scrollbar.

The easiest way to solve the verical scrollbar is to set `margin-bottom 7%` on the `div#box1`

Maybe you can use the css [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function which can help you calculate all the sizes.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm looking for the vertical one

Comment: @Pikappa Sure no problem

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to your html head section.

Comment: Still not working, the body goes overflow and I need no scrollbar and no overflow: hidden

Comment: if content overflows, my guess is that there is some content that is to wide for particular screen size.

Comment: Just what I'm thinking, but can't find the damn content ahahah I think maybe is for some content's size setted in px dimension, but can't figure out which one

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your responsive meta tag is missing.

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` inside the `<head>` tag

Can read about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/)

Comment: Still not working, the body goes overflow and I need no scrollbar and no overflow: hidden